# Facebooks Link preview

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've searched and searched and searched and cannot find a way for a person to post a link on a page from an app (As the page owner, of course), and have a link preview. It just posts the link instead of a preview like it would if you were posting via facebook. I would like to know if there is a way to override the link preview like this:

```
$x = $facebook->api('/'.$_POST["id"].'/link', 'post', array('message'=> urldecode($_POST["message"]), 'access_token' => $_POST["auth"], 'cb' => '', 'picture' => 'url to pic','description'=>'blah blah'));
```

Please help, don't really know what else to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of testing and came up with my answer:

```
$x = $facebook->api('/'.$_POST["id"].'/links', 'post', array('link' => $url,'caption' => $data['description'],'name' => $data['title'],'picture' => $data['thumbnail_url'],'url' => $url, 'message'=> urldecode($_POST["message"]), 'access_token' => $_POST["auth"], 'cb' => ''));
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a [link shorter service](https://linkfork.co) that allows customization of link preview. With linkfork.co you can customize the image, title, and description.